# Rally api to get data for Release Burnup

Tags: ios, rest, rally

I need rally api to get data for Release Burnup, to display chart in iOS. I tried rally rest api, but i'm having a trouble to figure out how it works. Can anyone help me? Here is the link for https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ where you can get more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Developer Portal [here](https://help.rallydev.com/for-developers) for links to API toolkits and for javascript [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/). There is no toolkit specific for iOS. A built-in [ReleaseBurnup](https://help.rallydev.com/progress-reports#rburnup) served by a first generation analytics service can be displayed via AppSDK2rc3 [StandardReport](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/standard-report) component. This is the same report that used to be available in AppSDK1, so for the supported config parameters see [this page](https://help.rallydev.com/standard-reports).

Comment: Thank you. Seems like there is no direct link to do that.

Comment: Also, other way to do this, is to grab direct graph from website and present UIWebview. That was my easy solution. Worked.

Comment: Can you please give me steps how to start? also i just want to get data and displayed it through highcharts

Comment: See examples and guides here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example                      https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide

Comment: Solved. Thank you.End up using loopback api.

Answer (score 0):

End up using look back apis, worked for me.